# Reorder items by data attribute in list with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I have this list

```
<div class="scroll-images">

  <div class="item" data-order="0">

  </div>
  <div class="item active" data-order="1">

    <div class="item" data-order="2">

      <div class="item" data-order="3">

      </div>
      <div class="item" data-order="4">

      </div>
      <div class="item" data-order="5">

      </div>
      <div class="item" data-order="6">

      </div>
      <div class="item" data-order="7">

      </div>
    </div>
```

I want to reorder it onClick. the clicked item should replace the second element (data-order = 1) but the order should stay. For example when I click data-order 6 I want to get:

```
<div class="scroll-images">

  <div class="item" data-order="5">

  </div>
  <div class="item active" data-order="6">

    <div class="item" data-order="7">

      <div class="item" data-order="0">

      </div>
      <div class="item" data-order="1">

      </div>
      <div class="item" data-order="2">

      </div>
      <div class="item" data-order="3">

      </div>
      <div class="item" data-order="4">

      </div>
    </div>
```

Is it possible with jQuery?

Comment: Easily possible. Look up how to remove and insert children in the jQuery docs.

Answer (score 0):

If the ordering should only be reflected visually, you can do it with flex-box and use the `order` property

More about `order` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items

```js
function changeOrder(){
   $("#three").addClass("last");
   $("#four").addClass("middle");
}
```

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  color: white;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.last{
  order: 4;
}

.middle{
  order: 3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flex-container">
  <div id="one">1</div>
  <div id="two">2</div>
  <div id="three">3</div> 
  <div id="four">4</div>
</div>

<button onClick="changeOrder()">
  change order
</button>
```

Comment: I know the order property but it is still same problem how to keep the order onClick and change the place of the clicked element

Comment: You can change that property on click

Comment: Yes but how do I do it with jQuery in a simple way? change the clicked item is easy. What about the rest?

Comment: @Asaf - I refactored my answer with a full example for you request. is that clear now?

Comment: Yes but I thought there's a better way than do it one by one. That was the question. Anyway תודה

Comment: I really appreciate your effort. Though it's not the answer I am looking for. I want a function that will work with any list length. Not a specific list. You got me?

Comment: You can use the `.replaceWith()` method - https://api.jquery.com/replacewith/

Comment: Does this help?